# Read csv file with smooks

Tags: java, file, csv, smooks

I'm trying to read an csv file with smooks 1.7 which works fine in junit, but on glassfish it throw an exception.

Seems the exception is complaining about an email1 atribute which doesn't exist in Customer entity, and it really doesn't exist, it is part of a list.
The main goal is save huge files in database

My smooks config:

```
<csv:reader        fields="email1,email2,email3,dddcel1,dddcel2,dddcel3,dddcel4,dddtel1,dddtel2,dddtel3,firstName,document,value,cc,$ignore$,bank,agency,$ignore$,titulo,tel_retorn,street,neighborhood,zip,city,state,$ignore$"       separator=";" indent="true" >
<csv:singleBinding beanId="customer" class="core.entity.Customer" />
</csv:reader>

<jb:bean beanId="customer" class="core.entity.Customer" createOnElement="csv-set/">

        <jb:value property="document" data="csv-set/csv-record/document" default="null"/>   
        <jb:expression property="invoiceDescription" execOnElement="csv-record">
            "Pending"
        </jb:expression>    
        <jb:value property="invoiceNumber" data="csv-set/csv-record/invoiceNumber" default="null" />  
        <jb:value property="contactPhone" data="csv-set/csv-record/contactPhone" default="null"/>           
        <jb:wiring beanIdRef="emails" property="emails" />   
        <jb:wiring beanIdRef="mobiles" property="mobiles" />
        <jb:wiring beanIdRef="phones" property="phones" />
        <jb:wiring property="invoiceDetail" beanIdRef="invoiceDetail" />
        <jb:wiring beanIdRef="address" property="address" />    

        <jb:expression property="billingFolder" execOnElement="csv-record">
            "DEFAULT"
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression property="status" execOnElement="csv-record">
            core.type.CustomerStatusType.PENDING
        </jb:expression>     

        <jb:expression property="discountValue" execOnElement="csv-record">            
            (customer.invoiceValue == null || customer.totalValue == null ) ? null : customer.invoiceValue - customer.totalValue  ; 
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression property="token" execOnElement="csv-record">
            core.util.TokenGenerator.generateToken(customer.document)       
        </jb:expression>  

        <jb:expression property="created" execOnElement="csv-record">
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new java.util.Date())))
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression property="domain" execOnElement="csv-record">                
            params.domainId
        </jb:expression>  

        <jb:expression property="invoiceValue" execOnElement="csv-record">
            (csvMap["valor_atual"] == null || csvMap["valor_atual"].isEmpty() ) ? null : Double.valueOf(csvMap["valor_atual"].replaceAll(",", ".")) ;
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression property="totalValue" execOnElement="csv-record">            
            (csvMap["oferta_cc"] == null || csvMap["oferta_cc"].isEmpty() ) ? null : Double.valueOf(csvMap["oferta_cc"].replaceAll(",", ".")) ;             
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression property="type" execOnElement="csv-record">
            (csvMap["type"] != null ? core.type.CustomerType.valueOf(csvMap["type"]) : core.type.CustomerType.PERSON) 
        </jb:expression>        

        <jb:expression property="firstName" execOnElement="csv-record">         
            .core.util.SmooksUtil.getCustomerFirstName(csvMap["firstName"]);         
        </jb:expression>   

        <jb:expression property="lastName" execOnElement="csv-record">    
            core.util.SmooksUtil.getCustomerLastName(csvMap["firstName"]);       
        </jb:expression> 

    </jb:bean>

    <jb:bean beanId="address" class=".core.entity.Address" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record">
        <jb:value property="street" data="csv-set/csv-record/street" default="null"/>
        <jb:value property="neighborhood" data="csv-set/csv-record/neighborhood" default="null"/>
        <jb:value property="city" data="csv-set/csv-record/city" default="null" />
        <jb:value property="zip" data="csv-set/csv-record/zip" default="null" />
        <jb:value property="state" data="csv-set/csv-record/state" default="null" />         
    </jb:bean>

    <jb:bean beanId="invoiceDetail" class="java.util.HashMap" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record">
        <jb:value property="@agency" data="csv-set/csv-record/agency" />        
        <jb:expression property="@bank" execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/bank">        
            core.util.BankUtil.retrieveBankName(_VALUE);          
        </jb:expression>   
    </jb:bean>

    <jb:bean beanId="csvMap" class="java.util.HashMap" createOnElement="csv-record">        
        <jb:value property="@firstName" data="csv-set/csv-record/firstName" /> 
        <jb:value property="@valor_atual" data="csv-set/csv-record/valor_atual"  />
        <jb:value property="@oferta_cc" data="csv-set/csv-record/oferta_cc" /> 
        <jb:value property="@type" data="csv-set/csv-record/type" />   

        <jb:value property="@email1" data="csv-set/csv-record/email1"  />  
        <jb:value property="@email2" data="csv-set/csv-record/email2"  />  
        <jb:value property="@email3" data="csv-set/csv-record/email3"   /> 

        <jb:value property="@dddcel1" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel1"  />
        <jb:value property="@dddcel2" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel2"  />
        <jb:value property="@dddcel3" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel3"  />
        <jb:value property="@dddcel4" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel4"  />    

        <jb:value property="@dddtel1" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel1"  />
        <jb:value property="@dddtel2" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel2"  />
        <jb:value property="@dddtel3" data="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel3"  /> 

    </jb:bean>

    <!-- EMAILS -->
    <jb:bean beanId="emails" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record">
        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/email1">
            (csvMap["email1"] == null || csvMap["email1"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["email1"];
        </jb:expression>
        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/email2">
            (csvMap["email2"] == null || csvMap["email2"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["email2"];
        </jb:expression>
        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/email3">
            (csvMap["email3"] == null || csvMap["email3"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["email3"];
        </jb:expression>    
    </jb:bean>


    <jb:bean beanId="mobiles" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record"> 
        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel1">
            (csvMap["dddcel1"] == null || csvMap["dddcel1"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddcel1"];
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel2">
            (csvMap["dddcel2"] == null || csvMap["dddcel2"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddcel2"];
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel3">
            (csvMap["dddcel3"] == null || csvMap["dddcel3"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddcel31"];
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddcel4">
            (csvMap["dddcel4"] == null || csvMap["dddcel4"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddcel4"];
        </jb:expression>        
    </jb:bean>



    <jb:bean beanId="phones" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record">        
        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel1">
            (csvMap["dddtel3"] == null || csvMap["dddtel3"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddtel3"];
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel1">
            (csvMap["dddtel2"] == null || csvMap["dddtel2"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddtel2"];
        </jb:expression>

        <jb:expression execOnElement="csv-set/csv-record/dddtel1">
            (csvMap["dddtel1"] == null || csvMap["dddtel1"].isEmpty() ) ? null : csvMap["dddtel1"];
        </jb:expression>
    </jb:bean>
```

The exception I got:

```
Warning:   Caught exception executing step: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.BatchletProxy.process(BatchletProxy.java:36)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchletStepControllerImpl.invokeBatchlet(BatchletStepControllerImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchletStepControllerImpl.invokeCoreStep(BatchletStepControllerImpl.java:108)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BaseStepControllerImpl.execute(BaseStepControllerImpl.java:144)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.ExecutionTransitioner.doExecutionLoop(ExecutionTransitioner.java:112)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.JobThreadRootControllerImpl.originateExecutionOnThread(JobThreadRootControllerImpl.java:110)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.BatchWorkUnit.run(BatchWorkUnit.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedFutureTask.run(ManagedFutureTask.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
Caused by: org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)
    at core.jobs.CustomerSmooksBatchlet.process(CustomerSmooksBatchlet.java:135)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.BatchletProxy.process(BatchletProxy.java:33)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.milyn.SmooksException: Error in 'org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator' while processing the visitAfter event.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.processVisitorException(SAXHandler.java:578)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.processVisitorException(SAXHandler.java:564)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.visitAfter(SAXHandler.java:401)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.endElement(SAXHandler.java:204)
    at org.milyn.delivery.SmooksContentHandler.endElement(SmooksContentHandler.java:96)
    at org.milyn.flatfile.FlatFileReader.parse(FlatFileReader.java:165)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:76)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.milyn.cdr.SmooksConfigurationException: Bean [customer] configuration invalid.  Bean setter method [setEmail1(java.lang.String)] not found on type [core.entity.Customer].  You may need to set a 'decoder' on the binding config.
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.setPropertyValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:560)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeAndSetPropertyValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:512)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.bindSaxDataValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:448)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.visitAfter(BeanInstancePopulator.java:378)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.visitAfter(SAXHandler.java:394)
    ... 23 more
```

The java code. The code below works fine when I'm running it in a junit test. But when I run on glassfish4.1 throw an exception

```
Smooks smooks = new Smooks(getParameters().getProperty("smooks-config"));
smooks.addVisitor(new SAXVisitAfter() {
        public void visitAfter(SAXElement element,
                ExecutionContext executionContext) throws SmooksException,
                IOException {

            Customer customer = (Customer) executionContext.getBeanContext().getBean("customer");
            List<String> emails = (ArrayList) executionContext.getBeanContext().getBean("emails");
            List<String> phones = (ArrayList) executionContext.getBeanContext().getBean("phones");
            List<String> mobiles = (ArrayList) executionContext.getBeanContext().getBean("mobiles");
            Address address = (Address) executionContext.getBeanContext().getBean("address");
            customer.setEmails(emails);
            customer.setPhones(phones);
            customer.setMobiles(mobiles);
            customer.setAddress(address);

            customerService.insert(customer);
        }
    }, "csv-set/csv-record");

    ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("domainId", getParameters().getProperty("domain"));
    executionContext.getBeanContext().addBean("params", params);

    String messageIn = StreamUtils.readStreamAsString(new FileInputStream(getParameters().getProperty("csvFilePath")));
    JavaResult result = new JavaResult();
    smooks.filterSource(executionContext, new StringSource(messageIn), result);
```

a piece of code of Customer entity

```
public class Customer implements Serializable    

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String document;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;   
    private Double invoiceValue;
    private Double discountValue;
    private Double totalValue;
    private CustomerStatusType status;
    private String contactPhone;
    private Date expirationDate;
    private List<String> emails;
    private List<String> mobiles;
    private List<String> phones;
```

Comment: That looks like a lot of boilerplate code which is badly coupled to your entity. You should give [super-csv-declarative](https://github.com/dmn1k/super-csv-declarative) a try.

Comment: Or [univocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) which not only is way faster than super-csv, but also requires way less code to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks, they seem good, I will check it out.